# CSS Solution for selecting every other ancestor

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can make this text alternate in color using CSS. I tried using whatever:nth-child(odd) but it doesn't work for nested divs.

```
<div class="whatever">
this is some text
  <div class="whatever">
  this is some text
    <div class="whatever">
    this is some text
      <div class="whatever">
      this is some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that if you want inverted colors, then a `filter: invert(1)` will do that: https://jsfiddle.net/L51dkc4s/. But for unrelated colors, that won't work.

Comment: The short answer is: no, you can't do that if you are using the exact same mark-up. Are you able to change the mark-up so the whatever class is not nested each time but added as siblings? Then you can use the nth-child(odd) nth-child(even) selectors. With this set up you can only do this using javascript..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for that:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("whatever");
let even = false;
for (let i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
   if (!even) {
     els[i].style.color = "red"; 
   } else {
     els[i].style.color = "blue";
} 
even = !even;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve alternate color using `nth-child` selector. Please have a look at the code.

```css
.whatever:nth-child(odd) {
        color: red;
      }
      .whatever:nth-child(even) {
        color: blue;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="whatever">this is some text</div>
    <div class="whatever">this is some text</div>
    <div class="whatever">this is some text</div>
    <div class="whatever">this is some text</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

:nth-child(odd) method is use when there is multiple child divs but here in your case every div has single child that's why it's not working.

**Case 1**:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("whatever");

for (let i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
   if (i%2==0) {
     elements[i].style.color = "Yellow"; 
    } else {
     elements[i].style.color = "Green";
     } 
}
```

```html
<div class="whatever">
this is some text
  <div class="whatever">
  this is some text
    <div class="whatever">
    this is some text
      <div class="whatever">
      this is some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Case 2:
If you want to change color of text using css then you can apply different class for that

```css
.text-green{
color:green;
}

.whatever{
color:yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="whatever">
this is some text
  <div class=" text-green">
  this is some text
    <div class="whatever">
    this is some text
      <div class=" text-green">
      this is some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP requested a solution that would work in CSS. You are using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to every other `<div>` with the first color.

```
.red { color: red }
```

Then assign the child selector `>` to `.red` with the second color. This ensures that only the direct children are affected and the color doesn't cascade down any further.

```
.red > div { color: blue }
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.red > div {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="x red">
  this is some text
  <div class="x">
    this is some text
    <div class="x red">
      this is some text
      <div class="x">
        this is some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```